# Can't convert string to int in Laravel in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am unable to convert a string to an int in PHP.

To give a little background, I am writing tests in Laravel

//    This is method from my test class

```
public function testIsNumberValidUnit(){

    $this->visit('/unitTest/isNumberValid/9647')
         ->see("0");
}
```

//this is my route that is called

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'unitTest'], function(){

        //tests method in post controller to see if phone number is valid
    Route::get('/isNumberValid/{fromNumber}', [

            'uses' => 'SomeController@isNumberValid',
            'as' => 'unitTest.isNumberValid'

    ]);

}
```

//This is my Controller method. $fromNumber comes as a string, and I am unable to convert it to an int, no matter what I do.

```
public function isNumberValid($fromNumber){

     //check if fromNumber is an integer else convert it to be an integer
        if(!is_int($fromNumber)){

    // $fromNumber = (int)$fromNumber;
       settype($fromNumber, 'integer');
       Log::info( $fromNumber . " is of type ". gettype($fromNumber));

    }
     //other code
}
```

Log record shows (and this does work):

```
9647 is of type integer
```

So far, I have tried the following to convert fromNumber to an int:

```
$number1 = $fromNumber+ 0;
$number1 = intval ($fromNumber);
$number1 = (int)$fromNumber
settype($fromNumber, 'integer');
```

but none have worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: So even though I was able to convert from string to int. I kept getting the same error about something not being able to convert to int. But on closer inspection i noticed the issue is with my twilio lookup which says "exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Object of class Twilio\Exceptions\EnvironmentException could not be converted to int'.

This question can be marked as closed.If needed I will create anothr question for my twilio issue.

Thanks guys!

Comment: intval($number) & (int)$number should both work.  See here.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4f9b68abafc2c9b34e09dc28f7f647e81b4352f0

Comment: need more code, question makes little sense as it stands

Comment: Why you say it acts like a string?

Comment: @Kris Roofe: I did gettype($fromNumber) and it returned string. I then tried to convert it to int using methods mentioned above, but it just refuses to convert. Those conversion methods work in other places, just not here.

Comment: @dagon I have added more code. hope that helps.

Comment: @MMMTroy I know it those commands work other places and in other methods. It doesnt work in this specific method of  mine. I tried them and didnt have much luck.

Comment: show the output of count the string.

Comment: and show your router

Comment: How are you confirming this isn't working?  Have you tried via a die & dump?  What do you get, if all you add to your controller function is dd((int)$fromNumber);?

Comment: that worked actualy. So it showing as integer. but I have a message saying "object of class twilio\exception,\environmentException could not be converted to int". Thanks guys. may be i should create another question for my twilio error